# Can you render a template from within the same template in grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm trying to do a recursive tree in grails.

My products/categoryList file looks like this

```
<ul>
    <g:each in="${shoppingsolutionproject.Category.findAllByParentCategory(parentCategory)}" var="parentCategory">
        <g:if test="${parentCategory}">
            <li>
                ${parentCategory.name}
                <g:render template="products/categoryList" model="[parentCategory: '${parentCategory}']" />
            </li>
        </g:if>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to get a recursive tree of all the categories in relation to their parent categories.  When I run this I get the following exception:

```
Error executing tag <g:render>: Error executing tag <g:render>: null
```

I'm starting to think I can't do this recursivly but if anyone can see what I'm doing wrong please let me know.

I verified if I change the template adress to `products/searchBar` everything renders, so it's an issue with categoryList calling itself.

Comment: I suspect your render should be: `<g:render template="products/categoryList" model="[parentCategory: parentCategory]" />` Give that a try.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore same result

Comment: '${parentCategory}' remove ' '